# Exchange 2007 Message Delayed Not In Queue And Not Sent

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a user who received this message overnight for about 100 emails on a tedious bulk email delivery task:

> Delivery is delayed to these recipients or distribution lists:
>
> XXX
>
> Subject: 2013 06 14 MCDONALD'S LICENSEES AUSTRALIA 2013-2014 INSURANCE
>   RENEWAL INVOICE
>
> This message has not yet been delivered. Microsoft Exchange will
>   continue to try delivering the message on your behalf.
>
> Delivery of this message will be attempted until 6/16/2013 11:22:22 PM
>   (GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney. Microsoft Exchange will
>   notify you if the message can't be delivered by that time.

So googling around, I checked the Queue in Exchange - there are no items waiting in the queue.

Then I checked the logs to see if the message has now been sent - it does not appear anywhere in the logs.  I also have a cloud based journaling service - there is no record of the email there either.

I need to get this fixed if I can, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 2):

OK it was a stupidly obvious reason: we have another server, public facing, which handles OWA and the like.  The missing items were in the queue on THAT server.

The primary Exchange Server (in case on SBS 2008 machine) was restarted for maintenance Saturday night, whilst some items were evidently still in the queue.  My guess is these items moved over to the other server when SBS went down for maintenance.  This other server was not configured to the Send Connectors.

So the resolution was to configure the second server to use the send connectors - and all sent properly!